# Changing inner content of a button

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, addeventlistener, togglebutton

I’m new to Js.. and I’m trying to change the inner Text of a button to toggle on click between `On` and `Off` using `addEventListener` method.

```js
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0];
const btn2 = document.createTextNode("Off");

btn.addEventListener.toggle("click", modifiedText() {
  // enter code here
});

ModifiedText() {
  // enter code here
}
```

```html
<button class=“btn”>On</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `addEventListener` on `button` and `get` or `set` the text inside button using `textContent` property.

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".btn");

button.addEventListener("click", function clickHandler( e ) {
   const btnText = e.target.textContent;
   if( btnText.toLowerCase() === "on") e.target.textContent = "Off";
   else e.target.textContent = "On"
})
```

```html
<button class="btn">On</button>
```